# How to get the Rails Asset Pipeline to exclude files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I get my build pipeline to ignore all the files that are postfixed with `_test.jsx` or or `_test.[any extension]`

I really don't want to put my tests in a `__test__` directory but rather have them be in the directory as the component.

Comment: Use the `test` directory. It's much easier for everyone else and you shouldn't buck the convention (and so lose built-in support of tools like Test::Unit and RSpec).

Comment: I see what you are saying, but I don't want to lose cleanliness of component based architecture which a framework should support and if I decided to take my jsx file and move it to another project it's easier to migrate it with tests

Comment: If your heart is set on that, then I hope you find an answer (I don't know enough myself to help). However, I can't emphasize enough that this is probably a bad move given the extensive and out-of-the-box support for the existing project architecture.